# Broken virtualenv after brew update

Tags: python, django, homebrew

I did an update/upgrade of homebrew.

After that, in all my django-projects virtualenvs, Python got broken.

What I did:

1. Reinstallation of virtualenv package:

   ```
   $ pip uninstall virtualenv && pip install virtualenv
   $ virtualenv --no-site-packages .virtualenv
   $ source .virtualenv/bin/activate
   ```
2. Rebuild virtualenv

   ```
   $cd .virtualenv/
   $ find . -type l -delete
   $ virtualenv .
   ```

   OK, Python back in business
3. Launch local server

   ```
   $python manage.py runserver

   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/marta/work/webDev/scaleway_servermg/vetrinamg/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
   Referenced from: /Users/marta/work/webDev/scaleway_servermg/vetrinamg/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
   Reason: image not found.
   Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
   ```
4. mysql issue

   ```
   $pip uninstall MySQL-python
   $pip install mysqlclient
   ```
5. Launch server again

   ```
   $python manage.py runserver

     [...]
     File "/Users/marta/work/webDev/scaleway_servermg/vetrinamg/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_thumbnails/engine.py", line 12, in <module>
     from easy_thumbnails import utils
     File "/Users/marta/work/webDev/scaleway_servermg/vetrinamg/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_thumbnails/utils.py", line 15, in <module>
     from easy_thumbnails.conf import settings
     File "/Users/marta/work/webDev/scaleway_servermg/vetrinamg/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_thumbnails/conf.py", line 334, in <module>
     settings = Settings()
     File "/Users/marta/work/webDev/scaleway_servermg/vetrinamg/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_thumbnails/conf.py", line 21, in __init__
     super(AppSettings, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
   ```

Could anyone point me to the correct solution?

I have the sensation that, as soon I fix a problem, a new one shows up.

Thank you for any help you could provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before becoming crazy, I decided to delete and recreate my virtualenv:

```
 virtualenv --no-site-packages .virtualenv
 source .virtualenv/bin/activate
```

install the project requirements:

```
pip install -r vetrinamg/requirements/local.txt
```

install mysqlclient:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

recreate my local db:

```
mysql -u root
mysql> CREATE DATABASE db_vetrinamg;
mysql> USE db_vetrinamg;
```

migrate my models:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

boom, everything is running smoothly!